# differential equations question - dealing with third order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not sure how to solve this equation: $$ty^{(3)} + {y^{(2)}} = 1$$

I know its not an initial value problem but I don't know where to go from here...does the Wronskian need to be used?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Reduce the order:

$$ty^{(3)} + {y^{(2)}} = 1$$
$$(ty^{(2)})' = 1$$
Integrate. Then it's a second order DE:
$$y'' = 1+\dfrac {c_1}t$$
Integrate twice.

Answer (score 2):

$$ty'''+y''=1$$

This is a third-order linear differential equation. Substitute

$$y''=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\big(y(t)\big)=v(t),\quad y'''=\frac{d^3}{dt^3}\big(y(t)\big)=v'(t)$$

then the equation becomes

$$ tv'+v=1$$
$$ v'=\frac{1-v}{t}$$
$$\frac{dv}{1-v}=\frac{1}{t}\,dt$$

integrate

$$v(t)=1+\frac{c_1}{t}$$

replace $v(t)$ with $y''$

$$y''=1+\frac{c_1}{t}$$

integrate

$$y'=t+c_1\log|t|+c_2$$

integrate once more.

Comment: More complete answer +1

Answer (score 2):

You can treat $y’’=u$ and rewrite this as $tu’+u=1$, which is first order linear, and may be solved using the integrating factor method  so you’d solve $$u’+\frac{1}{t}u=\frac{1}{t}.$$
However LostInSpace’s method is much better in the sense of getting to the answer directly.

Comment: Yes, as an alternative you can solve the reduced linear first order differential equation through the integration factor technique (+1).

Comment: Integrating factor is fine too +1